# System.IO.IOException: Невозможно создать файл, так как он уже существует

Tags: c#

Хочу переместить текстовый файл в другую папку. Если в каталоге "D:\myflora\folder" пусто, то файл перемещается, но при повторной попытке переместить файл, выскакивает ошибка. Что я не так делаю?

```
string fileName = @"D:\Orders\Order_"+ orderID + ".txt";
string dir = @"D:\myflora\folder";
File.Move(fileName, Path.Combine(dir, Path.GetFileName(fileName)));
```

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать-то? Как по-вашему нужно переместить файл, если он уже существует?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если файл уже существует, `File.Move` выбрасывает исключение. Можно вызвать метод [`File.Delete`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_File_Delete_System_String_) перед вызовом `File.Move`:

```cs
string fileName = @"D:\Orders\Order_"+ orderID + ".txt";
string dir = @"D:\myflora\folder";

string path = Path.Combine(dir, Path.GetFileName(fileName));
File.Delete(path);
File.Move(fileName, path);
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте такой вариант вызова `File.Move`, но он есть только в .NET Core 3.0 и позднее:

```
File.Move(fileName, Path.Combine(dir, Path.GetFileName(fileName)), true);
```

> public static void Move (string sourceFileName, string destFileName,
> bool overwrite);
>
> overwrite Boolean: true для перезаписи конечного файла, если он уже
> существует; в противном случае — false.